# How to serve webp images using htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to serve .webp images if the image (jpg or png) is available as webp. If not I want to show the jpg or png.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpe?g|png)(.*)$ $1.$2.webp [NC,L]

AddType image/webp .webp
```

The problem I need the final URL to be like:

```
"myurl.com/foo.jpg.webp"
```

If the webp file exists and if not I need:

```
"myurl.com/foo.jpg"
```

as a fallback solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the requested URL ends in `jpeg` or `png`, you might test for the corresponding `webp` with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp [L]
```

You may be more restrictive, if you like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp -f
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp [L]
```

If the condition and rule don't match, the request will fall through and serve the file (.jpg/.png) as is.

Answer (score 4):

This snippet detects if the browser [supports WebP](https://caniuse.com/webp) images and then serves a .webp image instead of jpg/png if a .webp file is available at the same location as the supplied jpg/png/gif

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Check if browser supports WebP images
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp

  # Check if WebP replacement image exists
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f

  # Serve WebP image instead
  RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=REQUEST_image]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Vary: Accept for all the requests to jpeg, png and gif
  Header append Vary Accept env=REQUEST_image
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Source of above example: https://github.com/vincentorback/WebP-images-with-htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Some browser don't fully support webp, you should add a condition to send only to supported browsers :

```
<Files *.webp>
    Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding"
    AddType "image/webp" .webp
    AddEncoding webp .webp
</Files>

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.webp [L]
```

Comment: Can You give me a hint how to change the code to work for files:
file1.jpg -> file1.webp
file2.png -> file2.webp
? Not to add .webp to full filename but to replace original file extension wit webp extension?

Comment: if you get myimage.jpg and myimage.jpg.webp in the same directory, and user request for myimage.jpg, the path stay myimage.jpg but the webp file is served. It works because browsers don't care about extention, it care about type MIME file